# How to add contact in list using (Send Grid) php api

Tags: php, email, curl, sendgrid

I am trying to add contact in list using php api but its throwing bellow snippet error

> string(51) "{"errors":[{"message":"request body is invalid"}]} " {"email":"hello@test.com","first_name":"hh","last_name":"User"}

I am using bellow snippet code:

```
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3';
$request =  $url.'/contactdb/lists/12345/recipients';  //12345 is list_id
$params = array(
'email' => 'hello@test.com',
'first_name' => 'hh', 
'last_name' => 'User'
  );
$json_post_fields = json_encode($params);
// Generate curl request
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = 
array("Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer SG.XXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Apply the JSON to our curl call
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post_fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
// Show me the result
var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);
}
echo $json_post_fields;
```

Can any one tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can use
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials goes here

Comment: Whether correct values were used in the `$params = array( array(` section ?

Comment: @Murali values are correct at array section.

Comment: You are not authenticating properly. See the docs here https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/authentication.html

Comment: @bwest can you provide me the sample code or suggest some answer on my question

Comment: @bwest see i have updated the code using correct authenticating method can you check this

Comment: @SanjayNakate I have added an answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at sendgrid API and then testing on my own server I was able to add contacts to the contact list. As you already created a list next step is to create recipients to be added to the list. You can do this way

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/';
$request =  $url.'contactdb/recipients';  //12345 is list_id
$params = array(array(
'email' => 'amitkray@gmail.com',
'first_name' => 'Amit',
'last_name' => 'Kumar'
));
$json_post_fields = json_encode($params);
// Generate curl request
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = 
array("Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer SG.000000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Apply the JSON to our curl call
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post_fields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
// Show me the result
curl_close($ch);
}
var_dump($data);
?>
```

After creating recipients you can now add them to list. You will get an id like this YW1pdGtyYXlAZ21haWwuY29t which is base64 encode of your email id.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/';
$request =  $url.'contactdb/lists/12345/recipients/YW1pdGtyYXlAZ21haWwuY29t';  //12345 is list_id

// Generate curl request
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = 
array("Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer SG.00000000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Apply the JSON to our curl call
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
// Show me the result
curl_close($ch);
}
var_dump($data);
?>
```

After adding that you can verify if user has been added to list

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/';
$request =  $url.'contactdb/lists/12345/recipients?page_size=100&page=1';  //12345 is list_id

// Generate curl request
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = 
array("Content-Type: application/json",
"Authorization: Bearer SG.000000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Apply the JSON to our curl call
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
// Show me the result

curl_close($ch);
}
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Note: best way is to create a class as most of the codes are being repeated. I will make a wrapper class for sendgrid and post it here soon with ability to do all task that is possible through sendgrid API.

Comment: thank you for "which is base64 encode of your email id" I'm having trouble finding this fact in the docs.

Answer (score 9):

You should inspect the request that you are sending and compare the JSON in the body to a valid request to really see what's happening. The output of your `json_encode` here will be an array, but the API expects an object. Your request body needs to be

```
[{"email":"hello@test.com","first_name":"hh","last_name":"User"}]
```

And what you are doing right now is sending

```
{"email":"hello@test.com","first_name":"hh","last_name":"User"}
```

You can fix this several ways. You could use your favorite string manipulation functions to append the brackets, or you could skip the encoding and send the JSON as a string (since you're specifying the content type).

Comment: As you said i have changed my code now i am able to add contact in list using $request =  $url.'/contactdb/recipients'; but i am still fail to add contact in specific list using {list_id } $request =  $url.'/contactdb/lists/12345/recipients';  //12345 is list_id                                this the link of new code http://pastebin.com/ErPkVaNa

Comment: As dsecribed in [the documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-a-Single-Recipient-to-a-List-POST), to add to a specific list, you have to provide a `recipient_id`. Recipients have a one-to-many relationship with lists.

Comment: $url.'/contactdb/lists/123/recipients/ddfg123 i have used in code but still its showing "message":"no valid recipients were provided"

Comment: The URL is fine. Your payload is wrong. Read the link I posted. The recipient_id goes in the payload, instead of email, name, etc. The list_id stays in the URL. The error message you are getting is completely correct, because you aren't providing a recipient_id. Please read the docs thoroughly before asking for more help.

Comment: i have tried that but still i am not able add contact in specific list, can you write in detail code in paste bin or in your current answer.

Comment: Please provide the HTTP Request you are sending to the API and I will help you debug it.

Comment: string(61) "{"errors":[{"message":"no valid recipients were provided"}]} " [{"email":"test@test.com","first_name":"gdgdhdh","last_name":"nnnnnnnnnnn"}]

Answer (score 0):

First think is you will need to insert your email to send grid recipients:

```
    <?php

    $curl = curl_init();

      $email = "example@mail.com";

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

      CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients",

      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "[{\"email\": \".$email.\"}]",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer SG.0000000",
        "content-type: application/json"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
        $a = json_decode($response);
        $b = $a->persisted_recipients; //get id of email 
        $r_id  = $b[0];                // store it

     }

    ?>
```

after that insert it in list by doing this way.

```
$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/123456/recipients/$r_id", 

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "null",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer SG.0000000000",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

for more info visit:https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).